# AWS Annotations Framework JWT Claims from API Gateway

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, jwt

I'm using the AWS Annotations Framework in dotnet, e.g.:

```
[LambdaFunction]
[HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/add/{x}/{y}")]
public int Add(int x, int y, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

but I've not idea how to retrieve JWT Claims (set by the API Gateway). I have searched the AWS documentation and [the Github project discussions](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/discussions/), but with no luck so far.

My guess would be to use the `[FromHeader]` attribute, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it to retrieve JWT Claims.

Before AWS Annotations, the code to retrieve the JWT Claims would be something like

```
public APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse LambdaMathAdd(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
   var email = request.RequestContext.Authorizer.Jwt.Claims["EmailID"];
   ...
```

but now I'm not using `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest`, I'm not sure how to retrieve the claims.

Many thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I'd missed a trick! I'm not in a position to deploy and test this at the moment, but by using dotPeek, I could look at the generated code.

If I update my test function to accept the `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest`  object, like so:

```
    [LambdaFunction]
    [HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/add/{x}/{y}")]
    public int Add(int x, int y, ILambdaContext context, APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest proxyRequest)
    {
        var emailClaim = proxyRequest.RequestContext.Authorizer.Jwt.Claims["emailID"];

        return x + y;
    }
```

I can see that the source generated code is:

```
public Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse Add(Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest __request__, Amazon.Lambda.Core.ILambdaContext __context__)
{
    //skip the irrelevant code ...

    var response = signUpFunction.Add(x, y, __context__, __request__);
```

In other words, the `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` object is passed to my `Add` function, and I can access all the bits I used to be able to

Many thanks,
Dan